# How to generate access token dynamically in application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am creating the JMeter script for application where in some requests receiving the access token (Oauth2) in request header. I need to create that dynamically as not getting the access token in response of any  request so that I can fetch and passed that further request.

Can you please provide the solution or logic to generate access token ?

I tried to generate the access token using the api who responsible to create token.

Also wrote logic to generate token.

But both options not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are several OAuth2 [Authentication and Authorization Flows](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow) and each flow can be implemented differently so there is no "solution" which will cover 100% of all possible cases. In case of SSO the token won't be directly returned, most probably it will be embedded into a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

The "logic" is pretty much straightforward: you need to replicate the network footprint of a real browser (or other client) with 100% accuracy, once you start sending the same requests as browser does - you will finally get the token.

[Record and replay](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) won't help as there are several dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter).

You can take a look at [oauth2-correlation](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/oauth2-correlation/src/master/) exaple project which demonstrates handling OAuth2 version of [Azure AD Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/overview-authentication) using correlation and it doesn't use the token anywhere.